# Searching in an array with custom comparator in java

Tags: java, arrays, search

Why does it always return `49999` no matter what `strToSearch` variable holds? Even with the clank search variable it returns the same. Have I missed something:

```
    String[] arr = new String[100000];
    String strToSearch = "12";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i+","+i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1 != null && o2 != null && !o1.isEmpty() && !o2.isEmpty() && o1.indexOf(",") != -1 && o2.indexOf(",") != -1) {
                String[] o1Arr = o1.split(",");
                String[] o2Arr = o2.split(",");
                Integer one = Integer.parseInt(o1Arr[0]);
                Integer two = Integer.parseInt(o2Arr[0]);
                return one.compareTo(two);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, strToSearch, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1 != null && o2 != null && !o1.isEmpty() && !o2.isEmpty() && o1.indexOf(",") != -1 && o2.indexOf(",") != -1) {
                String[] o1Arr = o1.split(",");
                String[] o2Arr = o2.split(",");
                return o1Arr[0].compareTo(o2Arr[0]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }));
```

My array contains comma separated values and I want to search based on string before comma in array elements. Is there any other simple solution available? I have also made a custom method which loops over array and finds the string but I'm looking for some alternatives.

Comment: Why are you using two different comparators? The second one does String comparison, so it will return a different ordering than the first. Also, the comparators should not return 0 on erroneous cases (i.e. when the value is null), that means that the items are equal (I guess that is related to having a wrong output).

Comment: Is it correct that you do integer comparision when sorting, but String comparison when searching? Look at your second comparator

Comment: Why do you think these alternatives would be faster than your custom method? Why don't you use the same comparator to sort and search?

Comment: @king_nak: Yes I have 2 diff comparator.

Comment: @JBNizet: Even if I use same comparator it returns `49999`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaDoc on `Arrays.binarySearch(...)` states that the array must already be sorted and thus the comparator actually compares the array value and the search string and not is *not* used for sorting the array again.

This means you get something like `compare(arr[x], "12")` and your if condition states that both strings must contain a comma, otherwise they are equal. And `"12"` doesn't contain any commas, thus making `"12"` equal to *every* element in the array (always returns 0).

*Edit*:

Looking at the source code seems to support my assumption.
There's this line, for example:

```
 //c is the Comparator
 //midVal is an element of your array 
 //key is the key parameter you passed to binarySearch(...)
 c.compare(midVal, key);
```

The reason for 49999 being returned is that the first `mid` value is at index `mid = (low + high) >> 1` which is `(0 + 99999) >> 1 == 49999` and since the comparator returns 0 the values are considered equal. And boom, the value is "found".

Comment: @mark Account for the fact that `o2` doesn't contain commas and adjust your if statement. You might also return a non-zero value for empty/null strings since those normally are not equal to the array elements (unless those are empty/null too).

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd if-Statement:
since your `strToSearch = "12"` and do not contain a `","`, the

```
o2.indexOf(",") != -1
```

will always return `false`.

Delete the hole `if`-Statement or at least the last part and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your binarysearch's comparator method. It should be re-written like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, strToSearch, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if(o1 != null && o2 != null && !o1.isEmpty() && !o2.isEmpty() && o1.indexOf(",") != -1) {
            String[] o1Arr = o1.split(",");
            int i1 = Integer.parseInt(o2);
            int i2 = Integer.parseInt(o1Arr[0]);
            return i2-i1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You assume that  `String strToSearch` is of type "12,12". To make this code work just change strToSearch

For example:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "12,12", new Comparator<String>)
```